# T-SQL simplify repeated query unions for each day of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've created the T-SQL code below to get the next nearest datetime value during the next 7 days.

The ScheduleDetail table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ScheduleDetail]
(
[uid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[scheduleRef] [int] NOT NULL,
[startTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[stopTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[validSunday] [bit] NOT NULL,
[validMonday] [bit] NOT NULL,
[validTuesday] [bit] NOT NULL,
[validWednesday] [bit] NOT NULL,
[validThursday] [bit] NOT NULL,
[validFriday] [bit] NOT NULL,
[validSaturday] [bit] NOT NULL,
[validHoliday] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

The `MIN(CAST(CAST(...) AS nextScheduleDateTime` is to get the date from that day of the week (after today) and add it to the schedule's startTime (as the startTime and stopTime fields are actually `TIME` types stored as `DATETIME`'s. Don't ask me why...)

The only difference between each is the value `@Sunday`, `@Sunday + 1`, etc. and the column names: `validSunday`, `validMonday`, etc.

```
DECLARE @waypointId INT = 100;   
DECLARE @Sunday INT = 1;

SELECT MIN(nextScheduleDateTime) 
FROM
    SELECT MIN(CAST(CAST(DATEADD(dd, (6 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @Sunday) % 7 + 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(ScheduleDetail.startTime AS TIME)) AS nextScheduleDateTime
    FROM WaypointEventLog INNER JOIN
         Schedule ON Schedule.scheduleRef = WaypointEventLog.ScheduleID INNER JOIN
         ScheduleDetail ON Schedule.scheduleRef = ScheduleDetail.scheduleRef
    WHERE WaypointID = @waypointId 
    AND Completed = 0
    AND Schedule.scheduleType = 6
    AND (validSunday = 1 AND DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) <> @Sunday)

    UNION

    SELECT MIN(CAST(CAST(DATEADD(dd, (6 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @Sunday + 1) % 7 + 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(ScheduleDetail.startTime AS TIME)) AS nextScheduleDateTime
    FROM WaypointEventLog INNER JOIN
         Schedule ON Schedule.scheduleRef = WaypointEventLog.ScheduleID INNER JOIN
         ScheduleDetail ON Schedule.scheduleRef = ScheduleDetail.scheduleRef
    WHERE WaypointID = @waypointId 
    AND Completed = 0
    AND Schedule.scheduleType = 6
    AND (validMonday = 1 AND DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) <> @Sunday + 1)

    UNION

etc for each day of the week.....
```

Is there any way to simplify this, maybe convert these to a UDF somehow? Or Similar.

I could probably do something with `EXEC` and `LEFT()` the column name but that feels wrong.

Comment: Yuck, that's ugly. Is there a reason the database uses `validMonday` etc instead of `validWeekday` for the 5 work-week days and `validWeekend` for Sunday/Saturday?

Comment: Can you give some sample data, both for `ScheduleDetails` and what you expect from your query?

Comment: "Get the next nearest datetime value during the next 7 days" is not clear to me.  The code looks way different than what I would think that means.  The common TSQL could be in a CTE.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for that table? Perhaps you could use a SQL fiddle like [this one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/29eb5/17)...

Answer (score 2):

### Syntax Issue

The derived table in the *FROM* clause needs to be surrounded by parentheses:

> ```
> DECLARE @waypointId INT = 100;   
> DECLARE @Sunday INT = 1;
> SELECT MIN(nextScheduleDateTime) 
> FROM
>     SELECT MIN(CAST(CAST(DATEADD(dd, (6 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @Sunday) % 7 + 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(ScheduleDetail.startTime AS TIME)) AS nextScheduleDateTime
> ```

Should be updated like this:

```
SELECT MIN(nextScheduleDateTime) 
FROM
    (SELECT MIN(CAST(CAST(DATEADD(dd, (6 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @Sunday) % 7 + 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(ScheduleDetail.startTime AS TIME)) AS nextScheduleDateTime
```

And then after the sub-queries:

```
    ) AS Subqueries
```

### Simplifying sub-queries

I believe (but haven't tested, since I don't have your data and expected output) that the `WHERE` conditions can be updated like below, which would allow combining the sub-queries into one, eliminating the usage of `UNION`:

```
DECLARE @waypointId INT = 100;   
DECLARE @Sunday INT = 1;

SELECT MIN(CAST(CAST(DATEADD(dd, (6 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @Sunday) % 7 + 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(ScheduleDetail.startTime AS TIME)) AS nextScheduleDateTime
FROM WaypointEventLog INNER JOIN
     Schedule ON Schedule.scheduleRef = WaypointEventLog.ScheduleID INNER JOIN
     ScheduleDetail ON Schedule.scheduleRef = ScheduleDetail.scheduleRef
WHERE WaypointID = @waypointId 
AND Completed = 0
AND Schedule.scheduleType = 6
AND 
(( validSunday = 1 AND DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) <> @Sunday ) OR 
        ( validMonday  = 1 AND  DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) <> @Sunday + 1) OR 
        ( validTuesday = 1 AND  DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) <> @Sunday + 2 ) OR 
        ( validWednesday = 1 AND  DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) <> @Sunday + 3 ) OR 
        ( validThursday = 1 AND  DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) <> @Sunday + 4 ) OR 
        ( validFriday = 1 AND  DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) <> @Sunday + 5) OR 
        ( validSaturday = 1 AND  DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) <> @Sunday + 6 ))
```

While it only contains the one table `scheduleDetail`, you can see this illustrated in [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/29eb5/19). Feel free to update that fiddle and provide more details about the other tables, plus the data in those tables.

#### Programmatic way of generating the query above

One approach you could take is to define a [CURSOR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql), and use that to loop through each field, adding the sub-queries to be joined via `UNION` to a long string. Originally I was thinking a `varchar(5000)` would be necessary but that was before I discovered the `UNION`s could be eliminated.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- field name 
DECLARE @rowNum varchar(10) -- row number 
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(5000) = 'SELECT MIN(CAST(CAST(DATEADD(dd, (6 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + @Sunday) % 7 + 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(ScheduleDetail.startTime AS TIME)) AS nextScheduleDateTime
FROM WaypointEventLog INNER JOIN
     Schedule ON Schedule.scheduleRef = WaypointEventLog.ScheduleID INNER JOIN
     ScheduleDetail ON Schedule.scheduleRef = ScheduleDetail.scheduleRef
WHERE WaypointID = @waypointId 
AND Completed = 0
AND Schedule.scheduleType = 6
AND ('

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  -- fetch columns to loop over
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC) - 1 AS RowNum 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
WHERE table_NAME = 'ScheduleDetail' and COLUMN_NAME like 'valid%' and COLUMN_NAME not like '%holiday' 
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name, @rowNum  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    --append WHERE condition
   SET @sql  = @sql + ' ('+ @name + ' = 1 AND DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) <> @Sunday + ' + @rowNum + ' )'+char(10)+char(13)   -- + CR + LF

   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name, @rowNum  
   if @@FETCH_STATUS=0 -- all except last condition
    BEGIN
        SET @sql  = @sql + 'OR'+char(10)+char(13)   -- + CR + LF
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN -- last condition
        SET @sql  = @sql + ')'+char(10)+char(13)   -- + CR + LF
    END
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

print @sql
```

That could be used to generate a Table-valued function or View.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite it as a [common table expression (CTE)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) using the relational operator [UNPIVOT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017).

#### Test records

[image: test records]

#### Results

[image: results]

#### Example SQL

```
PRINT '====================================================================='
PRINT 'Create temp table...'
PRINT '====================================================================='

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#schedule_detail') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #schedule_detail
GO

    CREATE TABLE #schedule_detail
    (
      [uid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , [scheduleRef] [int] NOT NULL
    , [startTime] [datetime] NOT NULL
    , [stopTime] [datetime] NOT NULL
    , [validSunday] [bit] NOT NULL
    , [validMonday] [bit] NOT NULL
    , [validTuesday] [bit] NOT NULL
    , [validWednesday] [bit] NOT NULL
    , [validThursday] [bit] NOT NULL
    , [validFriday] [bit] NOT NULL
    , [validSaturday] [bit] NOT NULL
    , [validHoliday] [bit] NOT NULL
    )

PRINT '====================================================================='
PRINT 'Insert test data...'
PRINT '====================================================================='

    INSERT INTO #schedule_detail (scheduleRef, startTime, stopTime, validSunday, validMonday, validTuesday, validWednesday, validThursday, validFriday, validSaturday, validHoliday) VALUES(101, '01-Jan-1900 08:00', '01-Jan-1900 13:00', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    INSERT INTO #schedule_detail (scheduleRef, startTime, stopTime, validSunday, validMonday, validTuesday, validWednesday, validThursday, validFriday, validSaturday, validHoliday) VALUES(102, '01-Jan-1900 09:00', '01-Jan-1900 14:00', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    INSERT INTO #schedule_detail (scheduleRef, startTime, stopTime, validSunday, validMonday, validTuesday, validWednesday, validThursday, validFriday, validSaturday, validHoliday) VALUES(103, '01-Jan-1900 10:00', '01-Jan-1900 15:00', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    INSERT INTO #schedule_detail (scheduleRef, startTime, stopTime, validSunday, validMonday, validTuesday, validWednesday, validThursday, validFriday, validSaturday, validHoliday) VALUES(104, '01-Jan-1900 11:00', '01-Jan-1900 16:00', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    INSERT INTO #schedule_detail (scheduleRef, startTime, stopTime, validSunday, validMonday, validTuesday, validWednesday, validThursday, validFriday, validSaturday, validHoliday) VALUES(105, '01-Jan-1900 12:00', '01-Jan-1900 17:00', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    INSERT INTO #schedule_detail (scheduleRef, startTime, stopTime, validSunday, validMonday, validTuesday, validWednesday, validThursday, validFriday, validSaturday, validHoliday) VALUES(106, '01-Jan-1900 13:00', '01-Jan-1900 18:00', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    INSERT INTO #schedule_detail (scheduleRef, startTime, stopTime, validSunday, validMonday, validTuesday, validWednesday, validThursday, validFriday, validSaturday, validHoliday) VALUES(107, '01-Jan-1900 14:00', '01-Jan-1900 19:00', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1);

PRINT '====================================================================='
PRINT 'Unpivot data...'
PRINT '====================================================================='

;WITH
schedule_detail_pivot
AS
(
    SELECT 
          [uid]
        , [scheduleRef]
        , [startTime]
        , [stopTime]
        , [day_of_week]
        , [validHoliday]
        , [nextScheduleDateTime] = DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', [startTime]), CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), [day_of_week] - 2)))
    FROM
        (
          SELECT 
              [uid]
            , [scheduleRef]
            , [startTime]
            , [stopTime]
            , [Sunday] = ([validSunday] + 0) * [validSunday]
            , [Monday] = ([validMonday] + 1) * [validMonday]
            , [Tuesday] = ([validTuesday] + 2) * [validTuesday]
            , [Wednesday] = ([validWednesday] + 3) * [validWednesday]
            , [Thursday] = ([validThursday] + 4) * [validThursday]
            , [Friday] = ([validFriday] + 5) * [validFriday]
            , [Saturday] = ([validSaturday] + 6) * [validSaturday]
            , [validHoliday] 
          FROM #schedule_detail
        ) AS cp
        UNPIVOT 
        (
          day_of_week FOR days_of_week IN ([Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday])
        ) AS tbl
    WHERE 
        1=1
        AND [day_of_week] != 0
)
SELECT 
      [uid]
    , [scheduleRef]
    , [startTime]
    , [stopTime]
    , [day_of_week]
    , [validHoliday]
    , [nextScheduleDateTime]
FROM 
    schedule_detail_pivot
```